# Would a question about the Ronald Opus joke be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask a question about the accuracy of the [Ronald Opus joke/fictional story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Opus)? However, I'm not certain whether that would be within the scope of this site, because I'm not sure whether the conclusions of a medical examiner are based on legal principles or something else.

Would this question be within the scope of this site?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a question about the role of medical examiners and their conclusions in the assessment and adjudication of a crime are on-topic.

On a bolder day I might attempt a more general statement of the form, "Questions about the role and conclusions of any authority or expert with any bearing on a decision of law are on-topic."  But I'm not feeling that bold today :D